# How do I interpret the results of lasso and ridge regression?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, lasso, ridge-regression

I have created a ridge and lasso regression model in R. From my understanding, the coefficients are interpreted differently from logistic regression. For instance, in logistic regression you may say males have a 4 times greater odds of developing a certain condition than females (assuming the coefficient was 4 and the predictor variable was males, with females as the reference). A significance value is also provided.

How do you interpret the coefficients in ridge and lasso regression, especially considering there is no p value?

Comment: Te lack of p-values and confidence intervals are a separate issue from what I address [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545901/how-do-you-interpret-lasso-dummy-coefficients/545903#545903), but for the point estimates, I argue that they should be interpreted the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not generally a good idea to interpret the coefficients in a elastic net model. The coefficients are penalized and are not suitable for inference about the true value of the parameter. These models are typically used for prediction, and should be evaluated based on the accuracy of their predictions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why penalising the coefficients makes the model unsuitable for inference?

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician this is an old question/answer and the answered has only ever answered this one question. You may get better responses by asking your own question.